# Convert a jQuery statement to simple javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do not wish to use the jQuery plugin or the . I wish to make all inputs' autocomplete off.

I have this code-

```
$("input, select, textarea").attr("autocomplete", "off");
```

Can this be put in normal javascript, if possible?

Comment: What have you done yet? Did you research about it yourself?

Comment: jQuery is normal JavaScript. What you probably meant was to directly use DOM API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** with **[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**

1. Get dom elements using **[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**
2. Convert it to array using **[`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)**
3. Iterate over elements using **[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** iterator
4. Set the attribute with help of **[`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)**

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input, select,textarea")).forEach(function(ele) {
  ele.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<input />
<select></select>
```

---

For older browser check polyfill options of [forEch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill) and [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill) methods.

---

Even you can simplify the code using **[`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)** with **[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("input, select,textarea"), function(ele) {
  ele.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<input />
<select></select>
```

Comment: `[].slice.apply(myElementList)` works like Array from.

Comment: awesome. Even better.